# How to dynamically get enum information from swagger

Tags: .net, angular, swagger

I am designing an Angular component that displays and saves configuration data. The component is all set up and working, but there are some configuration options that are using enums. Currently, I am just showing the enum value so people have to enter a number and must know what it means. Of course I want to show a dropdown instead, displaying the enum name.

The webapi uses .net 5 and the json serialization always uses the enum names (for the api controller and the swagger generation). So the possible enum names for the dropdown are included in the swagger specs.

I just cannot find a proper way to get the enum names into Angular. I guess (I have not tried) I could generate a webapi client from swagger (using something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-angular-generator). But that would leave me with a baked in enum. Instead I want Angular to pick up the enum names at runtime, since the enum entries are dynamic.

I was wondering if there is an off the shelf solution for this. One alternative I can think of is to expose the enum names with webapi methods that reflect the enums and return the names but I think there must be a better solution.

Excerpt from the swagger.json:

```
{
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "SettingOptions": {
        "enum": [
          "Option1",
          "Option2"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you directly fetch/access endpoint definition from swagger and just create a list of needed values (that you call enums) and show the in the UI?

Comment: @dplavcic Yes (I guess), have not tried this. I have only looked at the swagger spec in the browser so far - used it as (human readable) documentation. Do you know if it is common for a client to directly access the swagger definition?

Comment: It all depends on the context. Also it depends if the client has access to the swagger or not. If not, I would create all data client/UI needs on the back-end and you send it to the client/UI (assumption here is that the back-end can access the swagger def.)

It is really hard to give a definitive answer without further details about the project, e.g. is app for internal users only, who are the users, what is the business goal of the app..

Comment: @dplavcic Yes, the swagger.json (looked at it for the first time today, btw) is available to the Angular client  (while the webapi controllers require authentication). It is an intranet application. So is it good practice to pick up the info there? Just read it with an http call and process the file?

Comment: In your case, I would write down all possible way you can think of implementing this (time box this to 10 min), after that write all pros/cons for each possible implementation. Ask yourself if the solution meets the business requirements, how easy it is to implement, how flexible it is (not hard coding or having to regenerate model on back-end and redeploy the app), how maintainable it is? Also, do not forget about the context you are working in (intranet app for specific use case). 
But with all provided info you gave, I would go with the accessing the Swagger from the Angular.